# Network path of a IIS hosted website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

How to get the network path of a IIS hosted website in c#? 
I tried with `Server.MapPath("~/")`, it returns the physical path like (`C:\inetpub\....`); But I want it in the form (`http://IP_Add_of_hosted_machine/Website_Name/`).

Comment: you mean the url of the site ? Where and in what context are you trying this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this in Request you can use below code:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// will have something like this: http://IP_Add_of_hosted_machine/Website_Name/Default_1.aspx
```

If you are not in request context it is unknown for website where it is hosted. Moreover same directory can be hosted twice in IIS, so it will be difficult to say which one you want.